# Vuetify Text Field Label Alignment

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm building a simple registration page for a web-app.  I'm using vuetify components to build the page.  I have two text fields for taking a username and password.  The labels for the text fields show up on the right hand side of the text field. Any idea how I can get the labels to appear on the left side of the text field

I've tried to add custom css such classes to override the alignment but I couldn't get the expected result.  Here's the HTML without the custom classes:

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-card>
      <v-toolbar flat dense class="black" dark>
        <v-toolbar-title>Register</v-toolbar-title>
      </v-toolbar>
      <v-card-text>
        <v-text-field
          type="email"
          name="email"
          label="email"
          class="left-align"
          v-model="email"/>
        <v-text-field
          type="password"
          name="password"
          label="password"
          class="left-align"
          v-model="password"/>
        <br>
        <div class="error" v-html="error"/>
      </v-card-text>
      <v-card-actions>
          <v-btn class = "black" v-on:click="register" >Register</v-btn>
      </v-card-actions>
    </v-card>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

[image: Here's a picture of the interface]

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `reverse` prop

```
<v-text-field
reverse
type="email"
name="email"
label="email"
class="left-align"
v-model="email"/>
```

Comment: I've tried using the reverse prop but it does not affect the styling, the labels still appear on the right.

Answer (score 0):

When switching over to Vuetify 2 in an application formerly using Vuetify 1, make sure Vuetify is properly mounted within your application.  Add the following file in your project:

```
// src/plugins/vuetify.js

import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

const opts = {}

export default new Vuetify(opts)
```

And in the main.js file, pass the vuetify object to your Vue applicaiton:

```
// src/main.js

import Vue from 'vue'
import vuetify from '@/plugins/vuetify' // path to vuetify export

new Vue({
  vuetify,
}).$mount('#app')
```

Vist the [Vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start) Quickstart documentation for more info